Soql query: getting Folder child records when lookup field is polymorphic
I'm trying to retrieve a Folder of type ActionCadence, which contains records related to action cadence. However, I've encountered an issue with the lookup field on the ActionCadence object. The FolderId is a polymorphic lookup that can point to either Org, User, or Folder, and I'm having difficulty identifying the relationship name.
Here’s the SOQL query I’m using:
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    DeveloperName,
    Type,
    AccessType,
    (
        SELECT
            Id,
            TYPEOF Folder
                WHEN Folder THEN Type,
                                FolderId,
                                Name,
                                Description
            END
        FROM
            ActionCadence
    )
FROM
    Folder
WHERE
    Type = 'ActionCadence'

Questions:

How can I correctly structure this query to retrieve the action cadence records?
Is there a better way to handle the polymorphic lookup in this scenario?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I don't think the system can provide the same parent.child data structure with polymorphic relationship like you get with standard relationship (e.g. Account.Contacts, Account.MyCustomObjs__r), etc.  I think you'll need to query the two objects separately and build a map.

Unfortunately there is no space for apex, I was planning to use This query to export cadences via data tree

There are a number of standard relationships that don't have a relationship name, and thus cannot be queried in this manner. You can check for yourself by using a script such as the following:
for(ChildRelationship r: sObjectType.Folder.childRelationships) {
    System.debug(r.childsObject+', '+r.relationshipName);
}

If this script returns null for the relationship name, you can't produce a query in that direction.
That said, it should be possible to go from the other direction:
SELECT Id, Type, FolderId, Name, Description
FROM ActionCadence
WHERE FolderId IN (SELECT Id FROM Folder)

Though you'll still have to separate the records by folder in a script.
